# In which order do I need to multiply the (transformation-) matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $E$ the standard basis with
>
> $$M^E_E(\phi)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$A:=((1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,1,1)) \text{ and } B:=((-1,1,1),(1,1,1),(2,2,0))$$ are further bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Calculate $M^A_B(\phi)$.

Notation: $\color{red}{I^A_B}$ means we change from $\color{red}A$ to $\color{red}B$.
$$\begin{align}
M^A_B(\phi)&=T^E_B\cdot M^E_E(\phi)\cdot T^A_E\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}-1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ -1/2 & -1/2 & 1\\ 1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 3\\ 3/2 & 1/2 & 3/2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

or is it
$$\begin{align}
&=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\ 3 & 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot  \begin{pmatrix}-1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\ -1/2 & -1/2 & 1\\ 1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}-1/2 & 3/2 &  1\\
-5/2 &5/2 &5/2\\
-5/2& 3/2  & 2\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
? I'm not really sure, which one is correct.

Comment: please clarify your notaion on whether  $I^A_B$ means to change from basis B to A or vice versa

Comment: Sorry, $I^A_B$ means we change from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: It depends on whether you’re working with column or row vectors. The former is more common in mathematics.

Comment: @amd What would be correct of both ways if we're working with column vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former $M^A_B(\phi)=T^E_B\cdot M^E_E(\phi)\cdot T^A_E$   you recive vector $v_A$ representation of $v$ in basis $A$  $T^E_B\cdot M^E_E(\phi)\cdot T^A_E v_A = (T^E_B\cdot M^E_E(\phi)) v_E = T^E_B (\phi ( v) )_E = (\phi( v))_B $ as desired